Memory Optimizations for Collections
What is the best way to regain memory foot print of Collections like HashSet,List etc in .NET 6 and above?
Does any of the following will help?

a. Clear the collection and assign null
b. Just assign null.
c. Set Capacity to Zero and assign null

Which is best of the above or is there any thing else to reduce memory foot print of the collections quickly before GC happens?

The only thing that reclaims memory in the managed heap is the garbage collector. There's no mechanism to "hand back" chunks of memory via any other means. So no, there's nothing you can do "before GC happens"

None of these options will help. Never mind that "regain memory" is unclear. You gain nothing if you clear memory only to reallocate it. That's slower than using a garbage collector. You can avoid allocating extra memory if you specify even an approximate capacity in the List conctrusctor. You can reuse memory if you use ArrayPool, or if you clear the List and reuse it.

What is the actual problem behind this question?

I have List and HashSet used a lot and they are non static and they are class level in my case. I have optimized memory of my application with Disposable,UnSubsribing Events once done,Pre allocating size for dynamic collections,replacing string with string buider when and where required. But Still memory utilization is high.I am loading some large size collections , so I am thinking how to optimize those collections.

A large collection with many (large) elements will always require large (relatively) amounts of memory to store. There are ways to reduce the memory footprint, but they boil down to either (a) making the collection smaller (loading/ storing only the elements you need) or (b) making the individual object smaller (flyweight pattern etc.) and/ or a combination of the two. But to give you concrete advice we'd need to see much more of your code.

My idea is that .net core frees developers from having to manually release memory, and the garbage collector's optimizing engine determines the best time to perform a collection based on the allocations being made. It's completely automatical, therefore we don't require to manually relase the memory or manage GC in most of the scenarios. In your case, there're some large size collections, I'm afraid we'd better to conside scale out or scale up the server instead of considring release/optimize memory for these collections.

I found 2 document which might be helpful here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals   and    https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#gc

If you're using the collection correctly, then no: there's nothing extra you can do on most collections (there are some more exotic collections that for example use leased pool memory, but that's not the case by default). So: just drop the old reference on the floor (assign null on a new/different collection to whatever field was holding the reference to the collection), and let the GC get on with it.
It gets more interesting if you need to discuss the case where you have a leftover reference to the collection somewhere you've forgotten, that is reachable. In that scenario, a single such reference (perhaps from a captured variable scope in a long-lived callback) can keep all the list contents alive indefinitely. In that scenario, yes manually resetting the collection fully might help increase the things that can be collected next GC, but that's just papering over a symptom: the cause is that forgotten reference to the collection, so: fix that instead.

The best way to regain memory footprint for collections like HashSet and List in .NET 6 and above is to utilize the Clear() method for the collection to remove all elements, which allows the collection to release references to those elements. However, if you want to reclaim the memory immediately, you can also consider creating a new instance of the collection instead of just clearing it, as this forces garbage collection of the old instance.
Another approach is to set the collection to null if it is no longer needed, which allows the garbage collector to reclaim memory when it determines that the collection is no longer referenced. Finally, for large collections, you may also want to consider using the GC.Collect() method, although this should be used sparingly as it forces garbage collection and can impact performance.
For mastering visualization, memory, reading, and research skills, KeyToStudy offers valuable resources and tools!

"as this forces garbage collection of the old instance" - no, it does not. It may make it eligible for GC but it in now way guarantees when it may be collected.

To quickly reduce the memory footprint of collections like HashSet or List in .NET 6 and above, the best approach is:
a. Clear the collection and assign null.
This approach releases references to the elements, allowing for garbage collection to reclaim that memory.
In summary, clear the collection and then assign null for the best result.
.from other two i think option c) Set Capacity to Zero and assign null is also efficent but not necessary in most scenario

[citation needed] - if the list is no longer reachable (as hinted at by the "assign null" which suggests the intent is to make it unreachable), everything else here is irrelevant and will make zero difference to GC. If it is still reachable (via a secondary reference to the same collection object): fix that. Otherwise: just drop the reference on the floor (assign null or a new collection to whatever field is storing the collection reference), and let the GC deal with it.

If it's still reachable through another reference, that should be addressed first. Ultimately, if the goal is to make the list eligible for GC, simply dropping the reference (by assigning null or a new collection) is sufficient and effective., @Marc Gravell

Right: so, let's assume we've ticked the box of "If it's still reachable through another reference, that should be addressed first" - now: what is the point of your guidance "Clear the collection [...]" ? no: just drop the reference - literally nothing else is required or useful unless you're dealing with a very exotic collection type with special handling
